# pygame fall collision causes player to oscillates up and down

Tags: python, pygame, collision

i'm trying to create a falling effect in pygame but i'm stuck at a particular problem. That is when ever the player falls and collides with a platform, my player class begins to oscillate up and down. I'm sure this has to do with my update loop but i'm unsure as to what it is exactly. I've tried several methods like rearranging the hierarchy to no avail. I ended up searching online but got no answer. So if anyone can help with this i'd really appreciate it.

THANKS!

```
import pygame as pg
import os

#vector
VEC = pg.math.Vector2

def paint(parent, color=None):
    """ fills the background for surfaces.
        color: for none sprite surfaces optional parameter if given
    """

    #set background color based on surface type
    if color:
        #class based surfaces or sprites
        background = pg.Color(color)
    else:
        #none sprite surfaces usuallly not class
        background = pg.Color(parent.background)

    #check for image attribure
    #if found fill the image's backround
    if hasattr(parent, "image"):
        parent.image.fill(background)
    #if "image" not found fill the surface itself
    else:
        parent.fill(background)



class Asset(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    """ asset class functions as base class for various assets in this case
        either a player asset or a block asset group """

    #if the given family name(see bellow in constructor) is block,
    #all instances of block will be added to this group else its ignored
    GROUP = pg.sprite.Group()
    def __init__(self, parent=None, family=None, pos=None):
        """
            parent:surface asset is being rendered to
            family:type of asset(type is not used due to it being a buil-in)
            pos: position of asset
        """
        super().__init__()

        self.parent = parent
        self.family = family

        self.pos = VEC(pos)
        self.size = [20, 20]
        #background will be based on family
        self.background = {"block":"#000000","player":"#ff0000"}[self.family]

        self.image, self.rect = self.set_image()

        #see class documention for explanation
        if self.family == "block":
            Asset.GROUP.add(self)
        #if family is player add essential fields for physics
        else:
            #velocity
            self.vel = VEC(3, 3)
            #acceleration(x:friction, y:gravity)
            self.ac = VEC(.3, .3)
            #jump height
            self.height = 5


    def update(self):
        if self.family == "player":
            #fall code
            self.vel.y += self.ac.y
            self.pos.y += self.vel.y

            #prevents player from falling of the edge and adds teleportation
            if self.pos.x + self.size[0] <= 0:
                self.pos.x = 399
            elif self.pos.x >= 400:
                self.pos.x = 1 - self.size[0]

        #updates asset rect postion
        self.rect.topleft = self.pos

    def render(self):
        """ renders image to parent surface """
        self.parent.blit(self.image, self.rect)


    def set_image(self):
        """creates initial image and rect for sprite"""
        self.image = pg.Surface(self.size)
        paint(self)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = self.pos

        return self.image, self.rect

    def move(self, key):
        """handles player movmet"""
        for i in range(2):
            #checks for right or left movment
            if key[[pg.K_LEFT, pg.K_RIGHT][i]]:
                self.pos.x += self.vel.x*[-1, 1][i]

    def jump(self):
        """ handles jumping """
        self.vel.y = -self.height


def block_collision(player, blocks):
    """collision detection between blocks and player"""
    hit = pg.sprite.spritecollide(player, blocks, False)

    if hit:
        if player.rect.bottom >= hit[0].rect.top:
            player.pos.y = hit[0].rect.top - hit[0].rect.height
            player.vel.y = 0


def main():
    POS = [0, 0]
    SIZE = [400, 400]
    TITLE = "Test"
    BACKGROUND = "#ffffff"

    CLOCK = pg.time.Clock()
    FPS = 60
    RUN = True
    os.environ["SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED"] = "1"

    win = pg.display.set_mode(SIZE)
    pg.display.set_caption(TITLE)

    # create blocks group
    #NOTE:blocks do not need a variable instance because they are 
    #automatically added to the class group on construction
    for x in range(20):
        Asset(family="block", pos=[x*20, 380])

    #set player filed
    player = Asset(win, family="player", pos=[20, 20])


    while RUN:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                RUN = False
            elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_UP:
                    #player jump
                    player.jump()

        #player movement
        player.move(pg.key.get_pressed())

        #fill window background
        paint(win, BACKGROUND)

        #check for collision
        block_collision(player, Asset.GROUP)

        #update player
        player.update()
        #update block group
        Asset.GROUP.update()

        #render player
        player.render()
        #render block group
        Asset.GROUP.draw(win)

        pg.display.update()
        CLOCK.tick(FPS)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: first use `print()` to see values in variables, results of `if/else` statements, etc - maybe it will helps to find out why it doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two mistakes which together give problem

First:

```
player.pos.y = hit[0].rect.top - hit[0].rect.height
```

It makes no sense. `top - height` give the same as `bottom` so you have

```
player.pos.y = hit[0].rect.bottom
```

but you need `hit[0].rect.top` with `player.rect.bottom`

```
player.rect.bottom = hit[0].rect.top
player.pos.y = player.rect.y
```

(and here I don't know why you use `player.pos` if it always has the same value as `player.rect`, and `rect` has many useful fields like `rect.bottom`, `rect.center`, etc. and it automatically recalculates `rect.x`, `rect.y` when you change `rect.bottom`, `rect.center`, etc.)

So first correction is

```
if hit:
    if player.rect.bottom >= hit[0].rect.top:
        #player.pos.y = hit[0].rect.top - hit[0].rect.height

        player.rect.bottom = hit[0].rect.top
        player.pos.y = player.rect.y

        player.vel.y = 0
```

Second:

You should do all moves before checking collisionts

```
    # player movement
    player.move(pg.key.get_pressed())

   # update player
    player.update()

    #update block group
    Asset.GROUP.update()

    # check for collision - after all moves
    block_collision(player, Asset.GROUP)
```

---

Full code

```
import pygame as pg
import os

#vector
VEC = pg.math.Vector2

def paint(parent, color=None):
    """ fills the background for surfaces.
        color: for none sprite surfaces optional parameter if given
    """

    #set background color based on surface type
    if color:
        #class based surfaces or sprites
        background = pg.Color(color)
    else:
        #none sprite surfaces usuallly not class
        background = pg.Color(parent.background)

    #check for image attribure
    #if found fill the image's backround
    if hasattr(parent, "image"):
        parent.image.fill(background)
    #if "image" not found fill the surface itself
    else:
        parent.fill(background)



class Asset(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    """ asset class functions as base class for various assets in this case
        either a player asset or a block asset group """

    #if the given family name(see bellow in constructor) is block,
    #all instances of block will be added to this group else its ignored
    GROUP = pg.sprite.Group()
    def __init__(self, parent=None, family=None, pos=None):
        """
            parent:surface asset is being rendered to
            family:type of asset(type is not used due to it being a buil-in)
            pos: position of asset
        """
        super().__init__()

        self.parent = parent
        self.family = family

        self.pos = VEC(pos)
        self.size = [20, 20]
        #background will be based on family
        self.background = {"block":"#000000","player":"#ff0000"}[self.family]

        self.image, self.rect = self.set_image()

        #see class documention for explanation
        if self.family == "block":
            Asset.GROUP.add(self)
        #if family is player add essential fields for physics
        else:
            #velocity
            self.vel = VEC(3, 3)
            #acceleration(x:friction, y:gravity)
            self.ac = VEC(.3, .3)
            #jump height
            self.height = 5


    def update(self):
        if self.family == "player":
            #fall code
            self.vel.y += self.ac.y
            self.pos.y += self.vel.y

            #prevents player from falling of the edge and adds teleportation
            if self.pos.x + self.size[0] <= 0:
                self.pos.x = 399
            elif self.pos.x >= 400:
                self.pos.x = 1 - self.size[0]

        #updates asset rect postion
        self.rect.topleft = self.pos

    def render(self):
        """ renders image to parent surface """
        self.parent.blit(self.image, self.rect)


    def set_image(self):
        """creates initial image and rect for sprite"""
        self.image = pg.Surface(self.size)
        paint(self)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = self.pos

        return self.image, self.rect

    def move(self, key):
        """handles player movmet"""
        for i in range(2):
            #checks for right or left movment
            if key[[pg.K_LEFT, pg.K_RIGHT][i]]:
                self.pos.x += self.vel.x*[-1, 1][i]

    def jump(self):
        """ handles jumping """
        self.vel.y = -self.height


def block_collision(player, blocks):
    """collision detection between blocks and player"""
    hit = pg.sprite.spritecollide(player, blocks, False)

    if hit:
        if player.rect.bottom >= hit[0].rect.top:
            #player.pos.y = hit[0].rect.top - hit[0].rect.height
            player.rect.bottom = hit[0].rect.top
            player.pos.y = player.rect.y
            player.vel.y = 0


def main():
    POS = [0, 0]
    SIZE = [400, 400]
    TITLE = "Test"
    BACKGROUND = "#ffffff"

    CLOCK = pg.time.Clock()
    FPS = 60
    RUN = True
    os.environ["SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED"] = "1"

    win = pg.display.set_mode(SIZE)
    pg.display.set_caption(TITLE)

    # create blocks group
    #NOTE:blocks do not need a variable instance because they are 
    #automatically added to the class group on construction
    for x in range(20):
        Asset(family="block", pos=[x*20, 380])

    #set player filed
    player = Asset(win, family="player", pos=[20, 20])


    while RUN:

        # --- events ---

        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                RUN = False
            elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_UP:
                    #player jump
                    player.jump()

        #player movement
        player.move(pg.key.get_pressed())

        # --- updates --

        #update player
        player.update()

        #update block group
        Asset.GROUP.update()

        #check for collision
        block_collision(player, Asset.GROUP)

        # --- draws ---

        #fill window background
        paint(win, BACKGROUND)

        #render player
        player.render()

        #render block group
        Asset.GROUP.draw(win)

        pg.display.update()
        CLOCK.tick(FPS)

    # ---- end ---
    pg.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```